# VBS script won't launch without extension even though it's in PATHEXT

Tags: windows, command-line, path

I have some VBS scripts in a folder:

```
C:\Program Files\lin2nt\
   explore.vbs
   edit.vbs
   copyto.vbs
```

The folder `C:\Program Files\lin2nt\` is in my `Path` variable.

My `PATHEXT` is set as follows:

```
C:\>set pathext
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
```

Yet, at the command line, I have to specify the file extension. `explore.vbs` works, but simply `explore` does not. Windows complains that it can't find "explore".

I've tried restarting my machine, but to no avail. FWIW, I haven't touched the `PATHEXT` variable; it came out of the box with `VBS` as a listed file extension.

How do I get this to work without typing the file extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 more steps.

First we accociate the file extension with a file type

```
assoc .vbs=VBScript.File
```

Then we tell it how to execute the file:

```
ftype VBScript.File="%%SystemRoot%%\system32\CScript.exe" //E:vbs //nologo "%%1" %%*
```

This should complete the steps to enable vbs files to be run directly

Output from my system for each setting:

```
C:\xvi32>set pathext
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.CSH

C:\xvi32>assoc .vbs
.vbs=VBSFile

C:\xvi32>ftype VBSFile
VBSFile="%SystemRoot%\System32\WScript.exe" "%1" %*

C:\xvi32>dir *.vbs
 Volume in drive C is SYSTEM
 Volume Serial Number is 8490-5954

 Directory of C:\xvi32

08/15/2012  03:31 PM             5,271 testavaya.vbs
               1 File(s)          5,271 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  50,192,310,272 bytes free

C:\xvi32>testavaya
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

(the **testavaya** script takes a while to run, and contains proprietary information, so output cut off)

Comment: Novice question: does this go in the command prompt, or in the VBS scripts themselves? If it's the former, is this a one-time deal (via setting registry or something), or will I have to do this periodically? Thanks!

Comment: sorry - I should have clarified..   Yes, these go into the command line, and are a one time deal.

Comment: Hmm... now I have another issue. I copied your commands into the prompt verbatim, but it still cannot find `explore`. But now, if I type `explore.vbs` it says "Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permission to access the item." I check my permission (user level) and read / execute are checked. Any ideas?

Comment: try executing without the switches that specify engine and remove the splash line:  `VBSFile="%%SystemRoot%%\System32\WScript.exe" "%%1" %%*` - also, may need only one % sign, rather than the doubling %% I show.

Comment: Okay, I did `VBSFile="%SystemRoot%\System32\WScript.exe" "%1" %%*` and that lets me run `explore.vbs` again, but I still can't get `explore` to work; it says it's not found.

Comment: Take a look at the output of the setting of each command, and see if it matches yours

Comment: My settings are like yours, except for the fact that the path to `Wscript.exe` doesn't have `%systemroot%` -- it's expanded to `C:\Windows`. I tried using `%%`, but that only results in `%C:\Windows%`. Anyway, it works fine if I am using the command prompt. I can simply type in `explore` and it works. But I'd like to run it from the `Run` window, and that still says it cannot find `explore`. Any ideas on that? Thanks very much for your help so far.

Comment: For the runbox, it involves external programs, or editing the registry @ `HKLM\\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths` (see [here](http://commandwindows.com/runline.htm) for more details)